# AngularJs - weird error when applying a scope function to a variable in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat that prints out a list of figures

```
<td ng-repeat="field in objectKeys(estimate)" ng-init="amount = estimate[key]">
    <a href="#" 
    editable-text="estimate[field]" 

    onaftersave="updateFigure(field,value[field], estimate)" 

    tooltip="${{formatNumber(actualTable[account][field])}}" 

    tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" 

    tooltip-placement="left">

        {{formatNumber(estimate[field])}} 
    </a>
</td>
```

The good thing is, it works perfectly  i.e. printing the estimate figure out with a tooltip showing the actual amount.

However, the console keeps reporting error saying this `{{formatNumber(actualTable[account][field])}}` function call is problematic because the variable `actualTable[account][field]`is null. But it's not null, otherwise it can't be printed out correctly.

The screenshot of the error is

[image]

I must also add that the actual table data is requested separately to the estimate table via a async http call.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does `actualTable` populate through ajax ?

Comment: Through anm asycn http call yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{{ actualTable[account] && actualTable[account][field] && formatNumber(actualTable[account][field]) }}
```

Or add an `undefined` check in your `$scope.formatNumber` like

```
$scope.formatNumber = function(data) {
    if (data) {
        //your code
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm this is actually a good fix - we wait for the next $digest cycle to properly grasp the data. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case where the bindings are being evaluated in the angular digest before there are values populated.  The same thing happens when you use
 instead of  or  instead of

Try setting the value of formatNumber(actualTable[account][field]) in your controller scope to a variable, then binding that to the tooltip.  Angular expression syntax should be able to handle values on the scope without logging to console error.

E.g.

```
$scope.formattedValue = formatNumber(actualTable[account][field]);
```

In your html:

```
tooltip="{{formattedValue}}"
```

Bonus: you can use angular one-time binding (prepend your expression with "::") to drop the value off the digest cycle which will help keep your frontend speedy.